# Making one div never exceed the length of another div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div floating to the left and a div floating to the right. The one on the left is used for text and the one on the right for images. I've set it so that the divs are always a percentage size of the page so that they work on different browser sizes but when I put in two images or more, the right div will stretch to the bottom of the page leaving a lot of empty space in the left div. Is there any way to get my right div to always stay the same height as my left div and resize the images inside according to the dimensions of the div?

EDIT: I can use jquery.

Comment: Not using CSS alone, no.

Comment: u need to get left div height with js and set the right div height to that value, there is no way to do it with only css

Comment: Maybe you can go with a table layout. Though not recommended, but it serves the purpose.

Comment: I'm a little new to this so sorry if I'm unclear, I have to make a HTML/CSS website for a university assignment. I am allowed (and somewhat encouraged) to use jquery on my site, does that help? I'm using dreamweaver currently if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="images-holder">
    <div class="image-sample" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #000;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="image-sample" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #333;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="text-holder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam ducimus sint eaque quidem a ut deleniti voluptatibus consequatur modi quaerat eligendi doloribus illum expedita officiis repellendus mollitia facilis ratione minima.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images-holder {
    float: right;
}
.images-holder div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-holder {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B3DWj/)

The inline styles are sample to look like an image. Why not image? Don't know. xD

You can still use percents on the image holder, but not on the text holder.